# MSVC-10 Include Paths

Tags: visual-c++

How can I specify where MSVC searches for include files?  I want to add the boost headers to the search path.  I am not using a Visual Studio project, just the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit them into %INCLUDE% environment variable. You can find this via the System Properties property pages, e.g.

- (Windows 8+ only) Windows+X, Y, Advanced System Settings
- (Windows Vista, 7 only) Windows key (Windows+W on 8+), "env", Edit environment variables for your account
- (Windows XP) Control Panel, System Properties
- (All) Start->Run: `sysdm.cpl`

and then Advanced, Environment Variables.

The VS command prompt also adds its own; you could modify its batch file too to add your extras in. You'll find that at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat`.

(I'd already started typing about the IDE before you edited the question. [Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.TOOLSOPTIONSPAGES.PROJECTS.VCDIRECTORIES%29%3bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29%3bk%28DevLang-JAVASCRIPT%29&rd=true))

Comment: Thank you.  Extremely simple solution that was difficult for me to find :/

Answer (score 1):

Add the desired path(s) to the %INCLUDE% environment variable.