# How to add a default include path in MSVC++ 2012?

Tags: visual-c++, configuration, project

I would like to add an include and library path to the default configuration in VC++ 2012. I know I can add it manually per project, but there is a checkbox "Inherit from parent or project defaults". I would like to modify this "project defaults" so it applies to all my projects.

Any clue of where to edit this?

***EDIT
No, that answer doesn't help. I edited the vsvars32.bat file, run the bat to check that INCLUDE and LIB variables where updated with my own path (and they are), but when I start MSVC++ 2012 my added path is not included.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSVC-10 Include Paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401584/msvc-10-include-paths)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a pain, and there is a [blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx) that explains in detail, but in summary here's how you do it:

1. Open a project, any project.
2. From the menu, choose *View / Property Manager* (near the bottom of the menu)
3. In the property manager window, expand the project tree to show Debug and Release nodes
4. Expand either Debug or Release (it doesn't matter which)
5. Right-click on **Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user**
6. Choose *Properties* from the pop-up menu

You should see a dialog where you can edit the *VC++ Directories* entry like this:

[image: properties]

Once you *OK* through everything, any project you create or load will inherit these defaults.